# Magento 2 Issue with JavaScript and CSS Merge

Tags: magento2.2, javascript, optimization, merge-css, request

I have checked my site for speed and it was requesting 258 requests.

I have merged all JavaScript and CSS files and again tested it but still 251 requests are there.

While in view page source I can't find 251 requests. there is only one for CSS and 1 for JS.

So why it's showing on https://gtmetrix.com and other speed test sites.

Comment: How many images do you have on the page? Please do check the URL's loaded in waterfall chart in Gtmetrix. Your site is in production or development mode?

Comment: Production mode.

Comment: Have you checked waterfall chart in gtmetrix?

Comment: So without merging and minification how many requests are made?

Comment: near about 258 requests

Comment: So your minification and merge are not happening. So move the site to development mode check the configurations to enable minification and merge. Once enabling it move the site to production mode set the permissions for production mode and check it once again. If so files are not minified and merge remove all the static files and try deploying the files once again

Comment: But when view page source I can see it merged.

Comment: _cache/merged/f85696b5302d4da10f75b861ec1946e9.min.css

Comment: Can you please share your gtmetrix report?

Comment: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/staging2.officesleek.com/16MPVyji

Comment: CSS is merged fine and there is no problem about CSS. 181 js requests are made. It appears as if JS files are merged and minified. Please make sure of the js files you have excluded from merge in theme_directory/etc/view.xml

Comment: There are many files and directory in exclude tag
<item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.min.js</item>
<item type="directory">Magento_Ui::js/timeline</item>

Comment: Please compare it with that of the file in luma theme view.xml

Comment: Only one is additional in my theme <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js</item>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93627/discussion-between-raj-mohan-r-and-magecode).